# Get first day of week and last day in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, locale, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I want to get the fist day of current week with a specific locale for everyone.
For example in US week starts with Sunday and other countries on Monday.

I want to start on monday for everyone, this is because i want to use this for a SQLQuery.

I have this:

```
NSDate *weekDay = [NSDate date]; //any date in the week in which to calculate the first or last weekday   
 NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:weekDay];
[components setDay:([components day]-([components weekday]-[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] firstWeekday]))];

NSDate *firstWeekday = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
NSDate *lastWeekday = [[gregorian dateFromComponents:components] dateByAddingTimeInterval:7 * 24 * 3600 - 1];
NSLog(@"first - %@ \nlast - %@", firstWeekday, lastWeekday);
```

Which works fine if in your locale week starts with Monday but if starts with Sunday doesn't return what i want.

*So imagine today is 11 October 2015
With Sunday locale will return first day of the week 11, last day, 17
With Monday locale will return first day of the week 5, last day 11*

I want to return the second option wherever my app is executed.

Thanks.
Best regards.

Comment: As an English person, my week starts on a Monday...

Comment: Updated, affects to US but the problem is the same...

Comment: Did you try setting the locale of the calendar to systemLocale or setting firstWeekday?

Comment: What i want is to don't use systemLocale to prevent locales that first day is Sunday.

Comment: The documentation says: Use the system locale when you don’t want any localizations. Use the current locale to format text that you display to users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

cal.firstWeekday = 2;// set first week day to Monday
// 1: Sunday, 2: Monday, ..., 7:Saturday

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *startOfTheWeek;
NSDate *endOfWeek;
NSTimeInterval interval;
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear
       startDate:&startOfTheWeek
        interval:&interval
         forDate:now];
//startOfTheWeek holds the beginning of the week

endOfWeek = [startOfTheWeek dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval - 1];
// endOfWeek now holds the last second of the last week day

[cal rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
       startDate:&endOfWeek
        interval:NULL
         forDate:endOfWeek];
// endOfWeek now holds the beginning of the last week day
```

---

testing:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

NSLog(@"start: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:startOfTheWeek]);
NSLog(@"end:   %@", [formatter stringFromDate:endOfWeek]);
```

prints

```
start: 12.10.15, 00:00
end:   18.10.15, 00:00
```

So Monday is the beginning of the week

if I set

```
cal.firstWeekday = 1;
```

it will print

```
start: 11.10.15, 00:00
end:   17.10.15, 00:00
```

Sunday is the first day of the week

Comment: Hi:
Thanks but unfortunately doesn't work, if today is Sunday 11 and you excute your code the system returns that the first day of the week is Sunday 11 instead of Monday 5

Comment: Sure, it isn't an timezone issue due to printing it?

Comment: for example: I am in GMT+2, it is 1:12. for start of week I get `2015-10-11 22:00:00 +0000`, as this is GMT. If I add 2 hours, it is `2015-10-12 00:00:00`

Comment: @Miguel, please accept my answer, if it was useful. and do the same on your other questions, as you did not accept one answer!

Comment: Works nicely in 2023, thanks!